# How to set slider/picker initial value to `value` in p:calendar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

### Steps

- I have the following code in the `.xhtml` file:

```html
<p:calendar id="startTime" value="#{myManagedBean.startTime}"
            pattern="#{myManagedBean.timeFormat}" timeOnly="true"
            required="true"
            converter="TimeConvertor" showOn="button" readonlyInput="true"/>
```

- In a method labelled with `@PostConstruct` in `myManagedBean` I set `startTime` correctly.

### Expected

- The initial value shown in input is `startTime`.
- The slider/time picker widget value is `startTime`.

### Actual

- Indeed, the initial value shown in input is `startTime`, but **the slider/time picker widget value is `00:00`!**

### Screenshot

As you can see, the input is indeed initially set to `05:00 AM` but the slider/picket widget is initially set to `00:00 AM`, not `05:00 AM`

[image]

### The Question

How to set the initial value of the slider/picker of a `p:calendar` component?

### Misc.

Primefaces version: 7.0

Comment: PF 5.0?  PF 5.1? And [mcve] please

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added Primefaces version. For the minimal complete example, I'm still a beginner in JSF & learning to setup a new project in JSF would be too much work for the question purposes. I'm also not sure what files would be involved in the issue, what files/code would you suggest adding beside the provided?

Comment: Hi, ok, for a [mcve] see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and http://www.sscce.org/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ (no, I did not downvote)